# datePicker com nome concatenado

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Preciso chamar a função `datePicker` concatenando um nome fixo com o nome que trago de uma consulta. É possivel?

Tentei dessa forma:

```
$("validade_T'.$v_id'").datepicker({
```

Onde `validade_T` é o valor fixo e o `$v_id` seria o valor que vem do banco. Dessa forma retornou o erro dentro do jQuery.js:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: validade_T'.$v_id'
>
> throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

Comment: Isso vem de um `echo` em php ? Esse `$v_id`vem de onde ?

Comment: Sim, é de um PHP. O $v_id vem de uma pesquisa no banco Oracle.

Comment: ta apresentando o $v_id? se sim, nao precisa de o identificar assim no js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
var v_id = <?php echo $v_id; ?>; //criar uma variável para receber esse valor vindo do PHP
$('validade_T'+v_id).datepicker({  //concatenar a variável criada
```

Segue exemplo de como concatenar uma variável em `jQuery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 12; //aqui você só associaria o valor recebido da consulta (<?php echo $v_id; ?>)
  $('#data'+id).change(function() {
    var data = $('#data'+id).datepicker('getDate');
    $("#dataEscolhida").html(data);
  });
  $(function() {
      $('#data'+id).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
  }); 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Data: <input type="text" id="data12"></p>

<b>Data escolhida: </b><div id="dataEscolhida"></div>
```

Comment: Exatamente, era isso ai. Obrigado.